# How do I set up project as startup among a group of projects within a workspace in CodeBlocks?

Tags: codeblocks

I have created a workspace with different projects in CodeBlocks.
Each project has its own entry point (main).
However when I compile and run it always picks the same project.
How can I define wich is my startup project when I click RUN on CodeBlocks?
This is context menu on VisualStudio but here I do not see it.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of a *startup project* in a C::B workspace.

If you have a workspace `foobar` containing projects `foo` and `bar` then
one of those projects is always the *active* project. The active project
is the one that will be built (CTRL-F9) or run (CTRL-F10) from the **Build** menu.

By default the active project is the last project that you created. To make
`bar` the active project if it is not, right-click `bar` in the workspace
tree-view and select **Activate** from the menu (or simply double-click `bar` in the tree-view). Whenever you save the project your choice of active project is saved.

If you build the entire workspace from the **Build** menu, then by default
`foo` and `bar` are built in order of appearance in the workspace tree-view.
If you want to move `foo` from, say, first to second position in the default build
sequence, right-click `foo` in the tree-view and select 
**Project tree** -> **Move project down**.

If you always want `bar` to be built before `foo`, because `foo` depends on
`bar`, right-click `foo` in the tree-view, navigate **Properties...** ->
**Project dependencies...** and tick the checkbox that makes `foo` depend on `bar`.

Comment: Hi  Mike, I tried right click on project then Project Tree->and then I find two choices:"Activate Prior Project" or "Activate Next Project".  menu and indeed found

Comment: Hi Mike, I tried right click on project then Project Tree->and then I find two choices:"Activate Prior Project" or "Activate Next Project" but I cannot see how any of these can activate the project selected.

Comment: Hi Mike, I tried right click on project then Project Tree->and then I find two choices:"Activate Prior Project" or "Activate Next Project" but I cannot see how any of these can activate the project selected. However if I double click on a project and build it it does indeed activate it.

Comment: The active project is the one whose name appears in **bold** in the
workspace tree-view (in the projects panel at left of the IDE). If you right-click any project that is *not* the active project then
**Activate** is the *first item* on the menu (it is not under **Project tree**). If you do not see it there on the right-click menu, that is because the project you have clicked on is *already* the active project. And as I said, you can just double-click any project to activate it. You do not have to build it to activate it. When you do a build, the active project is the one that will be built.